# Accessing a function declared in App.js in an EJS file Using Nodejs and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have an `app.js` file where I've declared a function like so:

```
function acceptReq(req, res) {
     db.getDB().collection(collection).findOneAndUpdate({
         _id: ObjectId("5c94f444dab6e423a488d2ae")
     }, {
         $set: {
             requested: false,
             requests: {
                 user: undefined,
                 time: undefined
             },
             Booked: true
         }
     }, {
         returnOriginal: false
     }, (err, result) = > {
         if (err)
             console.log(err);
         else {
             req.flash(
                 'success_msg',
                 'Request Accepted!'
             );
             res.redirect('/dashboard/requests')
         }
     });
 }
```

I also have an ejs file in which I have a button that when clicked would execute this function in `app.js`:

```
<button  onclick="acceptReq()" class="btn btn-success  btn-block">Accept</button>
```

However, whenever I click the button, the file is not able to identify `acceptReq()`.

How do I properly declare the function for ejs to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you won't be able to. If you see the code acceptReq is most likely a API endpoint handler method, so you can probably define an API endpoint and use this as the handler and call that endpoint from by defining a function in javascript part of the ejs file and passing that function name in onclick of the button.

```
app.get('/update', function acceptReq(req, res) {
    db.getDB().collection(collection).findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: ObjectId("5c94f444dab6e423a488d2ae")
    }, {
        $set: {
            requested: false,
            requests: {
                user: undefined,
                time: undefined
            },
            Booked: true

        }
    }, {
        returnOriginal: false
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            req.flash(
                'success_msg',
                'Request Accepted!'
            );
            res.redirect('/dashboard/requests')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: so do you mean i declare the function twice? once in app.js and the other in the ejs?

Comment: @HusseinMenshawi Nope you need to define it only once, in app.js and in the ejs you can call this API using fetch function -- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: I tried using the fetch function in my ejs file and i think its going through the API in app.js but, my record is not updating in the database like it is suppose to.

Comment: @HusseinMenshawi Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: this is my fetch function :
`const button = document.getElementById('detal');         
                       button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                           fetch('/dashboard/requests/details/5c951ade25d3c63298e8e8b2',{
                               method: "put",
                               headers : {
                               "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                           },
                           redirect: "follow"
                           })  
                       });'

`

Comment: this is how the api is declared in app.js:
`app.put('/dashboard/requests/details/:id', function acceptReq(req, res){`

Comment: @HusseinMenshawi So this is a seperate issue then. Please mark the answer as correct if it is and put up a new issue with the related codes, else for a new user all of this might not make sense.

Comment: Okay will do that.